# How do you compute the determinant of a matrix where the same vector appears as a component of every column?

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume that every vector $\mathbf{x}_i$ is of length $n$. A textbook I'm reading seems to suggest that the following holds
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
\rule[-1ex]{0.5pt}{2.5ex} & \rule[-1ex]{0.5pt}{2.5ex} & & \rule[-1ex]{0.5pt}{2.5ex}\\
\mathbf{x}_0-\mathbf{x}_1 & \mathbf{x}_0-\mathbf{x}_2 & \cdots & \mathbf{x}_0-\mathbf{x}_n\\
\rule[-1ex]{0.5pt}{2.5ex} & \rule[-1ex]{0.5pt}{2.5ex} & & \rule[-1ex]{0.5pt}{2.5ex}
\end{vmatrix}
=
\frac{1}{n!}\:
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1\\
\mathbf{x}_0 & \mathbf{x}_1 & \cdots & \mathbf{x}_n
\end{vmatrix}\,.
$$
Is this so? If not, are there any other well-known means to simplify the left-hand side?

Comment: There seems to be a problem: the left-hand side has $n+1$ columns and the right-had side has $n$…

Comment: @Bernard - that is why there is the first row of 1's on the right-hand-side. This way it is still a square matrix, and it makes sense.

Comment: Oh: I see.A very compact notation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{vmatrix} 
1 & 1 & \ldots & 1 \\ 
\mathbf{x_0} & \mathbf{x_1} & \ldots & \mathbf{x_n}
\end{vmatrix}
= 
\begin{vmatrix} 
1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\ 
\mathbf{x_0} & \mathbf{x_1} - \mathbf{x_0} & \ldots & \mathbf{x_n} - \mathbf{x_0}
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix} 
1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\ 
0 & \mathbf{x_1} - \mathbf{x_0} & \ldots & \mathbf{x_n} - \mathbf{x_0}
\end{vmatrix}
$$

which is just

$$ (-1)^n
\begin{vmatrix} 
\mathbf{x_0} - \mathbf{x_1} & \ldots & \mathbf{x_0} - \mathbf{x_n}
\end{vmatrix}
$$

Comment: Can you comment on why the first equality holds?

Comment: The determinant is invariant under "shifting": Add or subtract one column to any other column and the determinant remains the same. If you are not familiar with it, it might seem confusing, but it really is a geometric fact. (Try it with the identity matrix)

Comment: Oh now I see what happened, the 1 in the first column canceled the ones in the other columns when you subtracted the first column from each.

Answer (score 1):

First evaluate the right hand side: expanding by the first row, we have

$$ \frac{1}{n!} \sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i \left| \begin{array}{cccccc}
| &  & | & | & & |\\
\mathbf{x}_0 & \cdots & \mathbf{x}_{i-1} & \mathbf{x}_{i+1} & \cdots & \mathbf{x}_n \\ 
| & & | & | & & |
\end{array} \right| $$

This is the alternating sum of the determinants of all-but-one of the $\mathbf{x}_i$.

Now look at the left-hand-side. Use multilinearity of the determinant. By that I mean the property that
$$ \left| \begin{array}{ccccc} | & & | & & | \\ \mathbf{v}_1 & \cdots & \mathbf{v}_i + \mathbf{u}_i & \cdots & \mathbf{v}_n \\ | & & | & & | \end{array} \right| 
= \left| \begin{array}{ccccc} | && | && | \\ \mathbf{v}_1 & \cdots & \mathbf{v}_i & \cdots & \mathbf{v}_n \\ | && | && | \end{array} \right| 
+ \left| \begin{array}{ccccc} | && | && | \\ \mathbf{v}_1 & \cdots & \mathbf{u}_i & \cdots & \mathbf{v}_n \\ | && | && | \end{array} \right|$$

If you apply this property to each column simultaneously, you see that the left-hand side is the sum over all possibilities where for each column you choose either $\mathbf{x}_0$ or $-\mathbf{x}_i$. But the determinant is also alternating, so any time two columns are the same, the determinant is zero. This means we only get the terms where we choose *at most* one column to be $\mathbf{x}_0$. So we get

$$
\left| \begin{array}{ccc} | && | \\ -\mathbf{x}_1 & \cdots & -\mathbf{x}_n \\ | && |\end{array} \right| 
+ \sum_{i=1}^n \left| \begin{array}{ccccccc} | && | & | & | && | \\ -\mathbf{x}_1 & \cdots & -\mathbf{x}_{i-1} & \mathbf{x}_0 & -\mathbf{x}_{i+1} & \cdots & -\mathbf{x}_n \\ | && | & | & | && | \end{array} \right|
$$

Now if you swap columns so that the $\mathbf{x}_0$ is always the first column, you get the factors of $(-1)^i$. Also, from pulling out the minus signs, each term gets a factor of $(-1)^{n-1}$ or $(-1)^n$.

I might have made a mistake somewhere, but I still don't see where the $n!$ comes from...